# Why does this glass of milkshake feel rubbery when I tap it?

Tags: acoustics

Every time I get a protein shake on the gym, I am puzzled by the way the glass responds to me tapping it with my fingernail.

[image]

If feels and sounds unlike glass, more like a softer elastic material.

I assume has something to do with the liquid probably having lots of air bubbles in it.

It is strange that if I hit it against my teeth, it feels less painful than if the glass is empty, despite being a lot more heavy.

Comment: **I assume has something to do with the liquid probably having lots of air bubbles in it**......try filling it with something with no air bubbles in it, see does it act the same way, I bet it will. It's still glass right? no matter what's in it.

Answer (score 1):

**Feels** is the keyword here.

The glass has a natural frequency of vibration, I am sure you have heard of some high notes cracking a glass.

By pouring in a dense liquid, you have altered the natural frequency but, no offence intended, tapping will give a different sound, and that's explained by above, but I doubt if the actual hardess of the  glass will change in any way at all.  If it really went rubbery, it would not maintain its shape, which it seems to be doing fine.

Comment: It is difficult to describe. I don't mean rubbery as in I can bend the glass, I mean in the way it vibrates when I tap it. It does not behave like a regular glass of water. Maybe you are onto something by mentioning the resonant frequency. Maybe it has a much lower resonant frequency than if it was filled with water. It does kind of ring at maybe 10-20hz. Maybe the bubbles are causing it to vibrate at such a low frequency that it sounds unlike any other glass of liquid I have ever come across.

Comment: HI Nick, I appreciate that you never meant rubbery in that sense, I just meant to stress how things **feel**, especially when you expect a different response when you tap a glass. I don't think the bubbles do anything except tune the vibrations a bit, I was trying to think of something like a light version of molasses or treacle, a dense substantial stuff that is not too dense to kill the vibrations completely. You could,seriously,  try a stout, like guinness and then add more and more sugar to increase its density. Don't drink it, yuk.

Comment: I have measured the resonant frequency with an instrument tuner on an iPad. With milk shake 150Hz, empty 1.2kHz, full of water 875Hz. I would like to try with a wine glass, as it will resonate better to get a more reliable reading from the tuner.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting! 
Can you try these out next time you go to the gym?

1) Try to pour water in it instead of milk shake. Does it behave in the same way?
    this would mean that the glass responds in a similar way to all fluid. Then we can think in the direction of acoustics.

2) Try to pour warm water in it instead of cold shake. Does it behave the same? Maybe the temperature has something to do with this.

3) Can you get a video of this and give a link! I'd love to see such a unique material. I personally have never come across such a material in internet or in real life. :D